# How to generate a numpy array with random values that are all different from each other

Tags: arrays, numpy, random

I've just started to learn about Python libraries and today I got stuck at a numpy exercise.

Let's say I want to generate a 5x5 random array whose values are all different from each other. Further, its values have to range from 0 to 100.

I have already look this up here but found no suitable solution to my problem. Please see the posts I consulted before turning to you:

- [Numpy: Get random set of rows from 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262654/numpy-get-random-set-of-rows-from-2d-array)
- [Numpy Random 2D Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984635/numpy-random-2d-array)

Here is my attempt to solve the exercise:

```
import numpy as np

M = np.random.randint(1, 101, size=25)
for x in M:
    for y in M:
        if x in M == y in M:
            M = np.random.randint(1, 101, size=25)
            print(M)
```

By doing this, all I get is a value error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Thus, my second attempt has been the following:

```
M = np.random.randint(1, 101, size=25)
a = M[x]
b = M[y]

for a.any in M:
    for b.any in M:
        if a.any in M == b.any in M:
            M = np.random.randint(1, 101, size=25)
            print(M)
```

Once again, I got an error: AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object attribute 'any' is read-only.

Could you please let me know what am I doing wrong? I've spent days going over this but nothing else comes to mind :(

Thank you so much!

Comment: np.random.random((5,5))*100

Comment: Focus on the test line - the `if`.  That's what's giving the problem.  Look at the `M==y` step.  Does it make sense to do an `if` test on that?

Comment: What's wrong with `choice`?  You are going at it the hard way, repeatedly creating the array of values until one meets the criteria.  Let `numpy` do the work for you.

Comment: When the error message tells you to use `any`, it means `(M == b).any()`.  `any` is boolean operation, meant to work with an array of `True/False` values.  Application to a number doesn't make sense (as in `a.any()`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insights @hpaulj, Now I've got a better understanding of the any function :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this will be ok for all your needs, but it will work for your example:

```
np.random.choice(np.arange(100, dtype=np.int32), size=(5, 5), replace=False)
```

Comment: `choice without replacement` is effectively what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
np.random.random((5,5))
```

to generate an array of random numbers from 0 to 1, with shape (5,5).

Then just multiply by 100 to get the numbers between 0 and 100:

```py
100*np.random.random((5,5))
```

Your code gives an error because of this line:

```py
if x in M == y in M:
```

That syntax doesn't work. And `M == y` is a comparison between an array and a number, which is why you get *ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()*.

You already defined `x` and `y` as elements of `M` in the `for` loops so just write

```py
if x == y:
```

Answer (score 1):

While I think `choice` without replacement is the easy way to go, here's a way implementing your approach.  I use `np.unique` to test whether all the numbers are different.

```
In [158]: M = np.random.randint(1,101, size=25)
In [159]: x = np.unique(M)
In [160]: x.shape
Out[160]: (23,)
In [161]: cnt = 1
     ...: while x.shape[0]<25:
     ...:     M = np.random.randint(1,101,size=25)
     ...:     x = np.unique(M)
     ...:     cnt += 1
     ...: 
In [162]: cnt
Out[162]: 34
In [163]: M
Out[163]: 
array([ 70,  76,  27,  98,  81,  92,  97,  38,  49,   7,   2,  55,  85,
        89,  32,  51,  20, 100,   9,  91,  53,   3,  11,  63,  21])
```

Note that I had to generate 34 random sets before I got a unique one.  That is a lot of work!

`unique` works by sorting the array, and then looking for adjacent duplicates.

A `numpy` whole-array approach to testing whether there are any duplicates is:

For this unique set:

```
In [165]: (M[:,None]==M).sum(axis=0)
Out[165]: 
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

but for another `randint` array:

```
In [166]: M1 = np.random.randint(1,101, size=25)
In [168]: (M1[:,None]==M1).sum(axis=0)
Out[168]: 
array([1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  2, 2, 1])
```

This `M[:,None]==M` is roughly the equivalent of

```
for x in M:
    for y in M:
        test x==y
```

I'm using `sum` to count how many `True` values there are in each column.  `any` just identifies if there is a True.